# Build a repetitive selector within a Less loop

Tags: css, less

I've seen various ways of looping in LESS, but I haven't found a way to build selectors (agglutinate would be the right term I guess).

For example, I'd like something like this:

```
.staticClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass{
    height: 20px;
}
```

Where `.repeatedClass` would be generated according to the loopcount. `.staticClass` and `.finalStaticClass` would be (as the name implies) static.

Also, the `height` property would be increased by 10 (or any given number) for every loopcount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about it somehow in this manner:

```
.generateClasses (@index, @n, @in:"") when (@index > 0) {
    @concatenate: "@{in} .repeatedClass";
    @selector: ~".staticClass @{concatenate} > .finalStaticClass";
    @{selector}{ height: unit(@n,px) };
    .generateClasses((@index - 1), (unit(@n) + 10), @concatenate);
}
.generateClasses(0, @n, @in){};

.generateClasses(4, 10px);
```

Where you pass on to the next loop the concatenated generated classes and each time add another class. The `@index` is the counter for the loop, and `@n` is the value that you want to increase.

**CSS output:**

```
.staticClass  .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 10px;
}
.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 20px;
}
.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 30px;
}
.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 40px;
}
```

### Edit - for older versions of Less:

in Less <= 1.3.3, you need to include the individual concatenating loops in a separate role (it is called `.test` in the example below), that confines the variable. Then you can loop through this, doing something along these lines:

```
.generateClasses (@index, @n, @in:"") when (@index > 0) {
    @concatenate: "@{in} .repeatedClass";
    @selector: ~".staticClass @{concatenate} > .finalStaticClass";
    .generateClasses((@index - 1), (unit(@n) + 10), @concatenate);
}
.generateClasses(0, @n, @in){};

.test(@i, @ni){
    .generateClasses(@i,@ni);
    @{selector} {
        height: @ni;
    }
}

.printClasses(@i:1,@ni:10px) when (@i > 0) {
    .test(@i,@ni*@i);
    .printClasses(@i - 1,@ni);
}

.printClasses(4);
```

output CSS will now be:

```
.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 40px;
}
.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 30px;
}
.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 20px;
}
.staticClass  .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 10px;
}
```

if you just need to generate a selector once at a time, you can skip the second loop and just call the `.test()` mixin wherever you need it.

Comment: Hey, tried your approach but my output differs from yours. For example, when compiling ".generateClasses(4, 10px);", i get the following: 

.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 10px;
}
.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 20px;
}
.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 30px;
}
.staticClass  .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass .repeatedClass > .finalStaticClass {
  height: 40px;
}

Comment: The problem is the leaking of variables out of their scope, which has been resolved in Less >= 1.4.0. Check if you are running the latest version of Less.

Comment: I added a solution for older versions of Less.

Comment: A whole lot of classes going on! Nice solution, +1.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution would be:

```
.staticClass {
    .loop(5);
    .loop(@n, @i: 1) when (@i <= @n) {
        .repeatedClass {
            > .finalStaticClass {
                height: 10px * @i;
            }
            .loop(@n, @i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn.staticClass%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.loop(5)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.loop(%40n%2C%20%40i%3A%201)%20when%20(%40i%20%3C%3D%20%40n)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.repeatedClass%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20.finalStaticClass%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20height%3A%2010px%20*%20%40i%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.loop(%40n%2C%20%40i%20%2B%201)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D)**.