# How to get nested structure in less using for loop

Tags: less

my css code which I want to get generate from my less code

here i am using less mixin functions Please suggest how to achieve this.
also index order is max to min so how to iterate from 0 to max in less.

```
// css code 

    .folder .folder-row {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.folder .folder .folder-row {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.folder .folder .folder .folder-row {
  padding-left: 60px;
}
.folder .folder .folder .folder .folder-row {
  padding-left: 80px;
}
.folder .folder .folder .folder .folder .folder-row {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
    // less code
           .loop (@index) when (@index > 0) {
                .folder {
                  .folder-row{
                  padding-left: @index * 20px;
                }
              } 
              .loop (@index - 1);
            }

            .folder {
              .loop(5);
            }
```

Comment: If you want each iteration to put its code nested in a code generated by previouse iteration, you (obviously) simply make the code invoking the said iteration to be nested as well. I.e., In simple words, to get the desired CSS you move your `.loop(@index - 1)` into `.folder {...}` block.

Comment: [Demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.loop(5)%3B%5Cn%5Cn.loop(%40n%2C%20%40i%3A%201)%20when%20(%40i%20%3C%3D%20%40n)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.folder%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.folder-row%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20padding-left%3A%2020px%20*%20%40i%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20.loop(%40n%2C%20%40i%20%2B%201)%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D). (Notice you need to also switch from "backward" loop to a "forward" one, otherwise you'll get your nesting in backwards too).

Comment: Adding my answer in the duplicate thread instead (curiosly missing the proper answer yet): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695787

Comment: excellent demo thanks i was just missing the place to call recursive function